# Long running processes causing the 502 Bad Gateway issue in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

ASP.NET Web API Core 2 method called multiple times and due to time-consuming. Azure gives a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I tried increasing the request time out but it didn't help. Error message got from Azure.[image]

Comment: How long do the requests take? I think there is a hard limit in Azure App Service.

Comment: The error mostly occurs after 3 min, sometimes 5 min

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase azure web app request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755403/increase-azure-web-app-request-timeout)

Comment: 230 seconds is 3 minutes and 50 seconds so sounds like you are hitting that.

Comment: Hosting the application in container or VM will help resolve this issue?

Comment: That's one way to solve the issue, but a better option would be to change the request such that it runs the long task in a background thread/worker, and the initial request returns status 202 + a URL the caller can use to check the status. Requires some rework of course, but ultimately that would be the better solution as maintaining VMs is pretty time-consuming. If you decide to run the app in a container, make sure the host allows for longer requests.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what juunas suggested, you can switch your Web API to Azure functions; which will scale automatically to accommodate your request load. Furthermore, you'll only pay for the compute cycles used instead of paying for allocating and using a VM.