# Streaming file to azure web app stops at 2 Go: SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, azure, file-upload, java-stream, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to upload a large file to azure data lake store, however the upload stops each time at 2 Go, I'm uploading the file using a stream from my post to azure webapp then to azure data lake store, here's the steps I did to debug the problem:

First I run the app locally so my local machine is the server, in this case the file is streamed to azure data lake correctly, however when I deploy the app to azure web app only 2Go is uploaded and it's stops there, the logs are not showing much, here's what I got:

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.read(NioChannel.java:147) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:173) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1280) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1223) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:729) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1084) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:263) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:343) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:659) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:366) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:921) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:900) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl.close(FileUploadBase.java:708) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:859) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.hasNext(FileUploadBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at com.upload.upload.UploadController.handleUpload(UploadController.java:42) [classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.37]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.37]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

My code:
Spring boot:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity handleUpload(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        log.info("UploadController started !");
        try {
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            FileItemIterator iterStream = upload.getItemIterator(request);
            while (iterStream.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = iterStream.next();
                String name = item.getName();
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    log.info("file is being streamed");
                    copyStreamToAzure(stream, getUploadPath() + "/" + name);
                    //convertInputStreamToFileNio(stream, name);
                } else {
                    String formFieldValue = Streams.asString(stream);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            log.error("failed!", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Fichier téléchargé avec succès.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=9001
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
server.connection-timeout=10000s
server.max-http-header-size=10000000
```

This web.config in the web app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4294967295" executionTimeout="3000000"/>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
      <httpPlatform processPath="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%\bin\startup.bat" arguments="-config D:\home\site\wwwroot\conf\server.xml start"> 
         <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_OPTS" value="-Dport.http=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Xms512m -Xmx2048m" />
            <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_HOME" value="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%" />
         </environmentVariables>
      </httpPlatform>
   </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

This is server.xml:

```
    ...
< Connector port="${port.http}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="127.0.0.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               connectionTimeout="6000000"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="16384"
               redirectPort="8443"
               connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" disableUploadTimeout="false"/>
    ...
```

At this point it's abvious that the problem is on azure web app, however I'm not sure why this is happening, especially that I'm using a stream and not uploading the file as a whole, anyone had a similiar problem ?

Comment: Are you possibly hitting the app service 230 sec request timeout? [Increase azure web app request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755403/increase-azure-web-app-request-timeout)

Comment: No it's not as there is interactions between the server and the client wich is the file is being streamed, it just stops at 2 Go after more than 10 minutes of successful uploading.