# What and where is Azure App Service Default Timeout value?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Can default timeout of Azure app service be viewed or changed in Azure using portal / Powershell / CLI?

Here is reference from General Settings: I could find none.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MughundhanRaveendran](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/839464/how-to-increase-api-timeout-on-azure-which-in-depl.html) and [KetanChawda](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/30795):

- 230 seconds is a default timeout configured at the Azure App service load balancer.
- This is a part of the Azure App service architecture and **cannot be configured or changed.**

References: [Why does my request time out after 230 seconds?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-230-seconds), [Time Out After 230 seconds](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05f254a6-9b34-4eb2-a5f7-2a82fb40135f/time-out-after-230-seconds?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) and [Increase azure web app request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755403/increase-azure-web-app-request-timeout)